# Persistence provided by Hibernate different from EJB 3.0

Tags: hibernate, jpa, ejb

I am new with hibernate. And I am confused that how is the persistence provided by Hibernate different from that provided by EJB?

Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 2):

[JPA (Java Persistence API)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_API) is part of the EJB spec, so I'd assume you are talking about it.

JPA is only a specification - it has a couple of interfaces and annotations, but that's all - almost no code written. Then there are implementations of that specification, which do the actual orm handling. Hibernate is such an implementation.

Comment: I think, to be precise, Hibernate existed before JPA, and was 'assimilated' into EJB spec as JPA...

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate is one implementation of the JPA (EJB persistence) specification (among other). It thus provides everything specified in the JPA spec, but adds specific features on top of that.